# Concave function divided by a convex function. What is the result?

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let us say that I have a function $f(x)$ that we know is a concave. And let us also say that we have another function $g(x)$ that is a convex.

If I make a new function, $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, will this new function be convex or concave?

I was wondering is there is an easy way to determine this, instead of deriving it from scratch, (like maybe there is a property or rules relating to operations on con-vex/cave functions or something). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general rule. Let $f(x)=1$; then $f$ is both concave and convex. Let $g(x)=e^{x^2}$, which is convex. However
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=e^{-x^2}
$$
is neither concave nor convex.

Comment: Thanks Julian. Actually for my case I can get more specific. The concave function is the geometric mean, and the convex function is the arithmetic mean. Their ration is always between 0 and 1 btw. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Julien I have heavily edited the question, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Spacey if you have a different question, why not ask it, and refer to the original question in a link? (and rollback your edits to your original question)

Comment: This is a completely different question. Please ask a new one and I will be glad to answer.

Comment: @TooTone Ok, I will do so.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Ok, sorry, let me roll it back, accept, and I will make a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Accepted. I made a new question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682381/is-the-geometric-to-arithmetic-function-convex-or-concave).

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, the ratio of a concave and a convex function is *quasiconcave*. Quasiconcavity and quasiconvexity are discussed in, e.g., [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/); consult them for details.

A function $f$ is quasiconvex if its superlevel sets $\{x\,|\,f(x)\leq\alpha\}$ are convex for all *fixed* $\alpha$; a function $g$ is quasiconcave if its sublevel sets $\{x\,|\,g(x)\geq\alpha\}$ are convex for all *fixed* $\alpha$. This is not the same as convexity/concavity; for instance, a function $f$ is convex if its epigraph $\{(x,y)\,|\,f(x)\leq y\}$ is a convex set. Clearly, convexity implies quasiconvexity, but not the other way around; and similarly for concavity and quasiconcavity.

Because they are not convex, they cannot be used in typical convex optimization software; but because they represent convex sets, they can be converted to compliant form. Returning to your case of a concave function $f$ divided by a convex function $g$. If the convex function $g$ is positive on its domain, then

$$f(x)/g(x) \geq \alpha \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad f(x) \geq \alpha g(x)$$

When $\alpha\geq 0$, this is a convex inequality that can be compatible with convex programming software. For $\alpha<0$, it is not convex.

If you wish to maximize a quasiconcave function (or minimize a quasiconvex function), you can solve a sequence of convex feasibility problems. Again, I would refer you to [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) for details.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! I'm sorry to bother you with a couple of question. It would be of great help if you could answer! So here we are. Is then the ration of a convex and concave function usually quasiconvex? Can you give the page on the Boyd & Vandenberghe book in which they discuss the ratio thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: New user "yan seve" [[ https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1253376/yan-seve ]] wanted to alter Michael to this Comment "Correction to Michael Grant's answer:{x|f(x)≤α} should be sublevel set instead of superlevel" : I am moving that Comment here to let the users  know about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but in case you need it in the future. Lemma 2.1 (Chandra) states that if $f(x)$ is *non-negative concave* and $g(x)$ is *strictly positive convex*, then $h(x)$ is *strong pseudoconcave*.

http://www.new1.dli.ernet.in/data1/upload/insa/INSA_2/20005a7f_278.pdf