# Is the geometric-to-arithmetic function convex or concave?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^N$. Also consider two functions, $g(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $a(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, representing the geometric and arithmetic means respectively.

The geometric mean function, $g(\mathbf{x})$, is concave. Furthermore, the arithmetic mean function, $a(\mathbf{x})$, is (I think), convex.

We also know that $0 \leq \frac{g(\mathbf{x})}{a(\mathbf{x})} \leq 1$ is always true.

My question is: Is the ratio $h(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{g(\mathbf{x})}{a(\mathbf{x})}$, convex or concave for this specific case?

I am currently trying to prove it by brute force on paper by deriving the Hessian matrix of $h(\mathbf{x})$, and then deriving its definiteness, but I was wondering if there might be an easier way.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "geometric/arithmetic mean" as a function of one input mean?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suppose $x$ is a vector

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fixed.

Comment: @GPerez I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither convex nor concave, but it is *quasiconcave*. See my [answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682271/concave-function-divided-by-a-convex-function-what-is-the-result/682522#682522) for more information, or go straight to [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).

The good news is that fixed lower bounds on the ratio can be represented in convex optimization problems; since, after all, 
$$g(x)/a(x) \geq \alpha \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad g(x) \geq \alpha a(x).$$
(This depends upon your claim that $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, so $a(x)>0$).
You can even maximize the ratio by solving a sequence of convex optimization problems.

The arithmetic mean, incidentally, is both convex and concave; that is, it is affine (indeed, linear). So unlike the more general answer I gave on the other page, the constraint conversion works even if $\alpha<0$. Of course, if $\alpha<0$, it is trivially satisfied.

Comment: Hi again MCG! I am studying that very book now in fact, (currently on Chap-III). :-) The 2nd paragraph sounds encouraging. Does this also then mean that I would be able to _minimize_ the ratio $h(x)$ in a similar way? (ie, Solving a sequence of convex opt problems).

Comment: No. As it is quasiconcave, you can only maximize it.

Comment: I see... after some thinking however, may one not be able to attain a minimization of this quasi-concave function after putting some additional constraints? (For example, a LSE penalization on $\mathbf{x}$ relative to some $\mathbf{x_0}$). I would intuitively think so. Might something like that work?

Comment: Well, it won't be convex or quasiconvex, no matter how you massage it. Whether it will *work* or not, who knows. That's the rub with non-convex problems. At least with concave minimizations you can be sure the solution is on the boundary of the feasible set; I'm not sure if that's the case with quasiconcave minimizations.

Comment: Interesting MCG. I am fortunate to be learning from you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_k>0$, then
$$
\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=n\frac{(x_1\dotsm x_n)^{1/n}}{x_1+\dots+x_n}.
$$
Fix $x_2=\dots=x_n=1$. It is easy to see that the resulting function
$$
n\frac{x_1^{1/n}}{x_1+n-1}
$$
is neither concave nor convex, implying the same for $g(x)/a(x)$.

Graph of $h(x,y)$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<10$:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Julian: Some followups: 1) Does this conclusion mean that this function $h(x)$ cannot be minimized/maximized ala convex optimization methods? 2) Since it is neither convex nor convex, does this mean the $\nabla^2 h(x)$, (the hessian) is strictly equal to a matrix of $0$s? Thanks.

Comment: $h$ is easy to maximize: $h(x,\dots,x)=1$. Choosing for instance $x_1=0$, $x_k\ne0$ for $k\ne1$ the minimum is seen to be $0$. As for the Hessian, the answer is no. Try it with the two dimensional case: $h(x,y)=2\sqrt{x\,y}/(x+y)$.

Comment: I graphed it on this end to inspect. I guess I am confused. 1) Since it is neither convex/concave, I take that to mean that we cannot use convex opt methods to minimize OR maximize this function, right? 2) If true, are you then saying that we can still hope to maximize/minimize this function, just not via convex opt methods? Thanks so much!

Comment: I just told you what the máximo and min. are.

Comment: Let me think about it some more. Sorry I am very new to this.